Glue DNS records not reflecting new address
On Ubuntu 24 using bind9 to config my DNS entries.
I got my domain pihosting.ca from GoDaddy and I updated my nameserver ns1.pihosting.ca to reflect the new server address 209.15.158.25. the old IP if needed ends with .18
I used dig/digwebinterface to query my DNS servers.
The server 209.15.158.18 the old server is still running and I can query it if I use the IP.
The new IP ending with .25 I can query any record just fine and lists the nameservers fine. But when I query NS type it hangs. I check the a entries in the old server and the NS records is directing to .25.
When I check propogation it still hasn't completed for ns1.pihosting.ca.
Have I misconfigured something wrong?
I was running ye DNS server for 2 years and I haven't encountered this issue before.
Also. I can't ping ns1.pihosting.ca saying host can't be reached and port 53 is open for both old and new servers.
